# Referencing a Column in the same table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Keeps telling me that I'm referencing SubTotal and I'm not sure how to fix that.

The error message I'm getting is "Column CHECK constraint for column 'Total' references another column, table 'Job'."

```
Create Table Job(
    JobNumber int not null
        Identity (1,1)
        Constraint PK_Job primary key clustered,
    Date datetime not null,
    Address varchar(100) not null,
    City varchar(50) not null,
    Province char(2) not null
        Constraint CK_Province Check (Province like '[A-Z][A-Z]'),
    PostalCode char(7) not null
        Constraint CK_PostalCode Check (PostalCode like '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]'),
    SubTotal money not null,
    GST money not null,
    Total money not null
        Constraint CK_Total Check (Total>SubTotal),               /*COME BACK TO THIS */
    ClientID int not null
        Constraint FK_JobToClient references Client(ClientID),
    StaffID int not null
        Constraint FK_JobToStaff references Staff(StaffID),
)
```

Comment: It's better to include the error message verbatim, not your interpretation of it.

Comment: Oh, sorry i forgot to include it my bad.

Comment: Oh yes Thank you !!!:)

Answer (score 0):

reference the constraint at table level not at field level.

in this way:

```
Create Table Job(
   JobNumber int not null
       Identity (1,1)
       Constraint PK_Job primary key clustered,
   Date datetime not null,
   Address varchar(100) not null,
   City varchar(50) not null,
   Province char(2) not null
       Constraint CK_Province Check (Province like '[A-Z][A-Z]'),
   PostalCode char(7) not null
       Constraint CK_PostalCode Check (PostalCode like '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]'),
   SubTotal money not null,
   GST money not null,
   Total money not null,               /*COME BACK TO THIS */
   ClientID int not null
       Constraint FK_JobToClient references Client(ClientID)
    ,
   StaffID int not null
       Constraint FK_JobToStaff references Staff(StaffID),
     ,Constraint CK_Total Check (Total>SubTotal)
```

)